# How to stop SQLAlchemy seeing "bind parameters" in an existing schema (for tusker)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, schema

I am trying to use Tusker to compare schema versions and check the current database is consistent.

My schema file contains raw SQL for database definitions, including plpgsql functions, in one of which is the line:

```
json = '{ "type": "Category", "data": {"empty":0} }';
```

This schema file is designed for direct import into psql, and works fine as is.

However, I'm now trying to deal with the schema-management tool using tusker and SQLAlchemy barfs, when it tries to run:

```
sql = sqlalchemy.text(sql)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

complaining:

```
Error executing SQL file schema_functions.sql: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter '0'
```

I can't modify the schema file (otherwise this would be trivial to add an escape character, but then it will break in psql);
So, is there any way to tell sqlalchemy to "not interpret integers as bind parameters"?

For more see: https://github.com/bikeshedder/tusker/issues/18

Comment: Are you able to modify the JSON to the extent of inserting a space between the colon and the zero?  That should work in both SQLA and psql.

Comment: Thanks. I tried modifying it, ad psql is OK but SQLA still complains. I think the invocation of SQLA (as used by tusker) is wrong, but I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: Curious - it worked for me with [this simple function](https://pastebin.com/dCgZbNk3).  Could you [edit] the question to include an example .sql file that will reproduce the problem?